# My avd runs forever and loop at boot

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

When i starts avd log cat gives me this:

```
07-03 10:07:01.636: E/Diag_Lib(863): [IMS_FATAL]| 155 | 866 |qpdpl:imsSignalHandler: GLobal data NULL or Event list size is 0
07-03 10:11:46.941: E/Diag_Lib(863): [IMS_FATAL]| 251 | 866 |qvp_rtp_handle_signals iRet : 0
07-03 10:11:46.941: E/Diag_Lib(863): [IMS_FATAL]| 238 | 866 |qvp_rtp_handle_signals qpDplMainLoop: Calling imsSignalHandler
07-03 10:11:46.941: D/Diag_Lib(863): [IMS_DEBUG]| 144 | 866 |qpDpl:imsSignalHandler
07-03 10:11:46.941: E/Diag_Lib(863): [IMS_FATAL]| 155 | 866 |qpdpl:imsSignalHandler: GLobal data NULL or Event list size is 0
07-03 10:11:46.941: E/Diag_Lib(863): [IMS_FATAL]| 243 | 866 |qvp_rtp_handle_signals add read fd : 8

device nexus 7
target api 17
IntelAtom x86
Ram 1024 heap 32
Storage 200
```

When i lower memory to 512 or 768, same result. loop forever. Can u help me ?
I would add that this avd works day ago perfectly. :D..

Ok it works when i will not choose: no skin or skin with dinamic hardware controls. WHY ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) as your emulator. It is fast and much easier to use than the AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, go in AVD Manager
Check is there any exclamation sign next to your virtual device. If there is sign then try repairing it from button next to it. 
If there is no sign then select that AVD in manager, click Start and select Wipe user data.

Comment: my avd is ok, and wipe user data doesnt help when i have no skin or skin with dinamic hardware controls.